# Mazda 6 (2004) won't start- cold temp, low oil, was unused for a week

Tags: starting, mazda, mazda-6, low-oil

I was out of town for a little over a week, while the weather has been below freezing. No access to indoor parking. Now that I've come back, the car won't start (no sound of the engine turning or anything) and the low oil light is on the dashboard while I'm turning the key.

I checked the dipstick (very low) and topped add about .5 liters of oil. It still won't start and the low oil light is still on. Won't be able to try a jump start for another 12ish hours.

Any advice? Should I try adding more oil even if it's above the minimum line on the dipstick now?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please contact the Community Managers to [get your two accounts merged](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the low oil light when clearly the operating voltage of your car is WAY below normal.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site! Sounds like a flat battery to me - especially given you say it's not turning over at all.

The oil pressure light is a red herring in this instance I think -they typically illuminate as part of the start up process, you just normally don't register it as it it will go out when the car starts. Don't add any more oil at this stage.

Comment: The OP says the dipstick read low.

Comment: @GdD yep.. but if there is sufficient oil to register on the dipstick at all it is not going to cause it not to turn over. And they have added 0.5l already, which should be enough to bring the level comfortably into the "normal" zone.

Comment: I see where you are coming from now and I agree, it just wasn't immediately clear from how you phrased it. The oil level won't be a reason it doesn't start.

Comment: A jump start successfully started the car. Thank you for your advice!